# Can't open luks encrypted drive with bash

Tags: bash, mount, cryptsetup, decryption

I try to mount an encrypted hdd. This works fine with this command in the terminal:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 myDisk --key-file /root/keyfile
```

The hdd is decrypted and mounted after this command. Since I want to do this auto. on boot, I tried to put this command in a bash script.
Just the command above, nothing else. For some reason, if I execute the script via terminal:

```
sudo bash myScript.sh
```

I get a message:

> Failed to open key file.

I tried it with the password instead:

```
echo "myPassword" -n | sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 myDisk -d -
```

which worked in terminal fine, but in the script it did not.
Using /etc/crypttab instead is not an alternative, since there are multiple ext. hdds used, which will later use the same keyfile, but I don't have access to the hdds and the UUIDs now.

I am grateful for any advice
BR Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out, when I change the order of the parameter in my command from:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 myDisk --key-file /root/keyfile
```

to:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /root/keyfile /dev/sda1 myDisk
```

It works beautiful.